# I try to get data from a report in a pdf file in order to use this in a python project, data is messy

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pypdf

I try to get data from a report in a pdf file in order to use this in a python project, but when a convert the pdf file to csv or text the data is messy.
[This report is a pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoaG0.jpg)

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the problem? What did you try so far?